# tikzmath arithmetic calculations using predefined variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, tikzmath

I'm trying to do calculations in `tikzmath` using some predefined variables. Here's an example of what I have

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    real \ang = 30;
    real \l = 2;
    coordinate \x = ({\l*cos(\ang)},{\l*sin(\ang)});
  }

  \node[draw] at (\x) {Something};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, errors are issued for the coordinate definition in `\tikzmath{}`. I have no idea where it goes wrong.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in [the examples in the manual](https://tikz.dev/library-math#sec-58.3) but badly explained, all `int(eger)`, `real` and `coordinate` variables need to be declared before they get assigned a value.

In this case, `\angl` and `\l` don't need to be declared as `real`s because it doesn't make a difference for the PGFMath functions.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    real \ang, \l;
    \ang = 30; \l = 2;
    coordinate \x;
    \x = ({\l*cos(\ang)},{\l*sin(\ang)});
  }
  \node[draw] at (\x) {Something};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, it works. Thanks a lot!